# bicubic Hermite spline interpolation: How to calculate the cross derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, interpolation, hermite-polynomials

I want to implement the [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) of a hermite spline (specifically the [akima spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akima_spline)). That means I have the points, and the derivatives in x & y direction for each point.
But I do not know how to calculate the **cross derivative** from that.

I know there is this in the Wikipedia article:

> To find the cross derivative fxy, take
> the derivative in both axes, one at a time. For example, one can first
> use the fx procedure to find the x
> derivatives of the points above and below the
> target point, then use the fy procedure on
> those values (rather than, as usual, the values of f
> for those points) to obtain the value of fxy(x, y)
> for the target point.

But I do not understand how those fx and fy are put together to form fxy.